# How to get last year's date range?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to get a date range between `LastYear/1/1` until `LastYear/12/31`

I know I could do this

`date_sub(now(), interval 1 year)`.  But this would get me 2013/03/08. Not sure how to change the day and the month.

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE dispatch_date between  `LastYear/1/1` AND `LastYear/12/31`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy to create the required dates:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE dispatch_date >= MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()) - 1, 1) -- first day of previous year
 AND dispatch_date < MAKEDATE(YEAR(NOW()), 1)  -- first day of current year
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [YEAR()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year).

```
SET @LastYear = YEAR(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR));
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE dispatch_date 
    BETWEEN CONCAT(@LastYear,'-01-01') AND CONCAT(@LastYear,'-12-31')
```